# Why is my clojure shell result not like what works in python?

Tags: python, clojure

When working in the python `repl` I often need to edit multiline code.

So I use `import os` then `os.system("notepad npad.py")`

In clojure I first run `(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])`

Then I run `(sh "notepad" "jpad.clj")`

This starts notepad but not in a useful way because the clojure `repl` now hangs. In other words, until I close notepad I cannot enter code in the `repl` and I want to keep both open.

I know I can easily open notepad without clojure so it is no big deal. However, is there a way for clojure to start an external process without hanging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`future` is a convenient way to leave work running in the background, and it is easy to check up on the process later.

```
user> (def notepad-process (future (sh "emacs" "jpad.clj")))
#'user/notepad-process
```

Edit the file for a while, then check on the process later if you want its exit code:

```
user> @notepad-process
{:exit 0, :out "", :err ""}
```

Comment: See also Raynes shell library [Conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) for generally useful shell stuff. `future` is what he uses too in examples where the shell task is running and not blocking the repl thread.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, `future` works. Thanks @Alex for mentioning `Conch`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `sh` to return immediately instead of waiting for notepad's exit code.  How about writing a `sh!` macro or somesuch that runs the original `sh` command on a new Thread?  If you're only using this as a convenience in the REPL, it would be entirely unproblematic.

*EDIT*

Arthur's answer is better and more Clojurian - go with that.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Now I know that `(= pythonic clojurian)` -> true